# Change Computer IP address using JAVA

Tags: java, ip, lan

I need to change computer IP address using java... I have tried this one but this doesnot work...

```
    String str1="192.168.0.201"; 
    String str2="255.255.255.0";
    String[] command1 = { "netsh", "interface", "ip", "set", "address",
    "name=", "Local Area Connection" ,"source=static", "addr=",str1,
    "mask=", str2};
    Process pp = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
```

Comment: any errors?  Do you have permission?  Does it work from the command line?

Comment: What does not work? Does it give you any error? Which one?

Comment: I dont know.. nothing is shown there...

Comment: didnt try that @ScaryWombat

Comment: @ZulkernainTasin what do you expect this code to do? This would change your local machine (ethernet) address. If you think that this would change your external IP address you're wrong.

Comment: no sir.. i dnt want that :p i need local change... but its not happening.. :(

Comment: have you attempted to run this code as root?

Answer (score 2):

You (probably) need to correctly concatenate those `key=value` arguments - as written they'll be treated as separate arguments, i.e.

```
{..., "addr1=" + str1, "mask=" + str2 };
```

Comment: do the same with `name=\"Local Area Connection\"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
String[] command1 = { "netsh", "interface", "ip", "set", "address",
"name=\"Local Area Connection\"" ,"source=static", "addr="+str1,
"mask="+str2};
```

Note that now the arguments after the = are not separated by spaces. Also note the double quotation marks sourrounding Local Area Connection.

If this doesnt work either, try enclosing Local Area Connection in single quotation marks like this:

```
"name='Local Area Connection'"
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure of the name of your interface

use `netsh interface ipv4 show config` in cmd to check the name of your connection

Answer (score 0):

I tested out the code you posted, and here is the error I got

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type IOException

```
at DaysinaMonth.main(DaysinaMonth.java:9)
```

the error was found on this line:

```
Process pp = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
```

I have no suggestions for fixing this, but I can say that looking at the code provided, the runtime seems to be useless unless used to form a loop, but since you didn't make the IP set as a randomly generated number, that would have no reason to be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DaysinaMonth {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{
        String str1="192.168.0.201"; 
        String str2="255.255.255.0";
        String[] command1 = { "netsh", "interface", "ip", "set", "address",
        "name=", "Local Area Connection" ,"source=static", "addr=",str1,
        "mask=", str2};
        Process pp = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
        System.out.print( pp);
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but the returns are strange: `java.lang.ProcessImpl@659e0bfd`

no errors are found and my ip has been altered, but not in an expected way.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library with JNA (Java 17) can do this , I hope anybody help me for improvements .
**Note**: Currently support Linux OS.
[JSysBox](https://github.com/Java-OS/jsysbox)

Current Features :

- **Networking** :

  1. list available interfaces
  2. Set/Get interaface ip address
  3. Interface statistics
  4. IfUp/IfDown
  5. Add/Delete/List routes (specific method to set default gateway)
- **FileSystem**:

  1. Mount/Umount/MountPoints Filesystems
  2. Set/Get system environments
  3. Set/Get hostname
- **Date and Time**

  1. Set/Get system time zone
  2. Set/Get system date and time
  3. Sync system to hardware clock (like: hwclock --systohc)
  4. Sync hardware to system clock (like: hwclock --hctosys)